# using Lucene Arabic Analyzer to index collection of arabic text files

Tags: lucene, arabic

I am trying to use Lucene to index a collection of Arabic files. I can do this for English files with StandardAnalyzer, however for Arabic files I don't know how to use ArabicAnalyzer. Can some one help with some example or piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the contrib analyzers libraries:  [Arabic Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ar/ArabicAnalyzer.html).